# Refactoring Switching On Types Code Smell When Adding Method to Type Seems Inappropriate

Tags: oop, polymorphism, refactoring

Let's say I have the following method that, given a PaymentType, sends an appropriate payment request to each facility from which the payment needs to be withdrawn:

```
public void SendRequestToPaymentFacility(PaymentType payment) {

    if(payment is CreditCard) {
      SendRequestToCreditCardProcessingCenter();
    } else if(payment is BankAccount) {
      SendRequestToBank();
    } else if(payment is PawnTicket) {
      SendRequestToPawnShop();
    }

}
```

Obviously this is a code smell, but when looking for an appropriate refactoring, **the only examples I have seen involve cases where the code executed within the conditionals are clearly the responsibility of the class itself**, e.g. with the standard example given:

```
public double GetArea(Shape shape) {
  if(shape is Circle) {
    Circle circle = shape As Circle;

    return circle.PI * (circle.radius * circle.radius);
  } else if(shape is Square) {
    Square square = shape as Square;    

    return square.length * square.width;
  }
}
```

`GetArea()` seems like a pretty reasonable responsibility for each Shape subclass, and can of course be refactored nicely:

```
public class Shape
{
  /* ... */
  public abstract double GetArea();
}

public class Circle
{

  public override double GetArea()
  {
    return PI * (radius * radius);
  }

}
```

However, **`SendRequestToPaymentFacility()` does not seem like an appropriate responsibility for a `PaymentType` to have.** (and would seem to violate the Single Responsibility Principle). And yet I need to send a request to an appropriate `PaymentFacility` based on the type of `PaymentType` - what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider adding a property or method to your `CandyBar` class which indicates whether or not the CandyBar contains nuts.  Now your `GetProcessingPlant()` method does not have to have knowledge of the different types of CandyBars.

```
public ProcessingPlant GetProcessingPlant(CandyBar candyBar) {

    if(candyBar.ContainsNuts) {
        return new NutProcessingPlant();
    } else {
        return new RegularProcessingPlant();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hm - perhaps I used a bad example. The situation I am thinking about is where something needs to be done based on the distinct type. Let me change the example in the question

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add an IPaymentFacility interface parameter to the constructors for the individual PaymentType descendants. The base PaymentType could have an abstract PaymentFacility property; SendRequestToPaymentFacility on the base type would delegate:

```
public abstract class PaymentType
{
    protected abstract IPaymentFacility PaymentFacility { get; }

    public void SendRequestToPaymentFacility()
    {
        PaymentFacility.Process(this);
    }
}

public interface IPaymentFacility
{
    void Process(PaymentType paymentType);
}

public class BankAccount : PaymentType
{
    public BankAccount(IPaymentFacility paymentFacility)
    {
        _paymentFacility = paymentFacility;
    }

    protected override IPaymentFacility PaymentFacility
    {
        get { return _paymentFacility; }
    }

    private readonly IPaymentFacility _paymentFacility;
}
```

Rather than wiring up the dependency injection manually, you could use a DI/IoC Container library. Configure it so that a BankAccount got a Bank, etc.

The downside is that the payment facilities would only have access to the public (or possibly internal) members of the base-class PaymentType.

**Edit:**

You can actually get at the descendant class members by using generics. Either make SendRequestToPaymentFacility abstract (getting rid of the abstract property), or get fancy:

```
public abstract class PaymentType<TPaymentType>
    where TPaymentType : PaymentType<TPaymentType>
{
    protected abstract IPaymentFacility<TPaymentType> PaymentFacility { get; }

    public void SendRequestToPaymentFacility()
    {
        PaymentFacility.Process((TPaymentType) this);
    }
}

public class BankAccount : PaymentType<BankAccount>
{
    public BankAccount(IPaymentFacility<BankAccount> paymentFacility)
    {
        _paymentFacility = paymentFacility;
    }

    protected override IPaymentFacility<BankAccount> PaymentFacility
    {
        get { return _paymentFacility; }
    }

    private readonly IPaymentFacility<BankAccount> _paymentFacility;
}

public interface IPaymentFacility<TPaymentType>
    where TPaymentType : PaymentType<TPaymentType>
{
    void Process(TPaymentType paymentType);
}

public class Bank : IPaymentFacility<BankAccount>
{
    public void Process(BankAccount paymentType)
    {
    }
}
```

The downside here is coupling the Bank to the BankAccount class.

Also, [Eric Lippert discourages this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx), and he makes some excellent points.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can take here is to use the Command pattern. In this case, you would create and queue up the appropriate command (e.g. Credit Card, Bank Account, Pawn Ticket) rather than calling a particular method. Then you could have separate command processors for each command that would take the appropriate action.

If you don't want the conditional complexity here, you could raise a single type of command that included the payment type as a property, and then a command processor could be responsible for figuring out how to handle that request (with the appropriate payment processor).

Either of these could help your class follow [Single Responsibility Principle](http://deviq.com/single-responsibility-principle/) by moving details of payment processing out of it.